# Populating poplist in plsql from oracle db

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I am trying to create group-subgroup creation mechanism, in my db i have **GROUPS** table which consists of three columns

```
| ID | GROUP_NAME | PARENT_GROUP_ID |
```

if the group is not subgroup to any other group parent_group_id is null. When group is created I have two inputs, first for group name based on **:GROUPS** data block which is based on **GROUPS** table, and the second should be drop down list, populated with the rows from **GROUPS** table  where parent_group_id is null. For this purpose, when creating layout for the data block, I have chosen data type for `parent_group_id` as `char` and item type as `List Item`.

Creating group without choosing parent group is okay. However the list is not being populated, I have when-new-form-instance trigger at form level which calls the procedure to populate list

```
PROCEDURE CBS_WNFI_LIST IS
 rg_groups RecordGroup; 
 rg_group_name VARCHAR2(5) := 'GROUP_NAME'; 
 nDummy NUMBER;
BEGIN 
 rg_groups := Find_Group(rg_group_name); 
 -- Delete any existing Group first 
 IF NOT Id_Null(rg_groups) THEN 
    Delete_Group(rg_groups); 
 END IF;
  -- Now create a Record Group using a SQL query 
  -- Your Query must have a Label and a Value (two Columns) 
  -- and the data types must match your item type 
  rg_groups := Create_Group_From_Query(rg_group_name,'SELECT group_name, to_char(ID) FROM GROUPS WHERE PARENT_GROUP_ID IS NULL'); 
  -- Populate the Record Group 
  nDummy := Populate_Group(rg_groups); 
  -- Populate the List Item 
  Populate_List('PARENT_GROUP_ID',rg_groups);
END;
```

on new-form-instance i get the error **ORA06502 UNPROCESSED EXCEPTION**

Can you help me find out where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrongly specified length of rg_group_name as 5, while length is more than 5 characters.